# Paypal buy now button in email does not work

Tags: paypal

I implemented paypal buy now button in email that is sent from my site. I created the the button(html button) dynamically using PHP(amount is variable for the button).

But the button in email takes me to a different website when i click it. Only yahoo mail take me to the "Your order summary" page (which is the actual page i want to go) all other email client(gmail, hotmail) open http://client.updatemyprofile.com/d-l-2AD73FFF-l-o this page. the html code that shows in email are like below.

```
<form target="_blank" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return theMainWindow.showFormWarning(this)" method="post">
    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://client.updatemyprofile.com/d-l-2AD73FFF-l-o" lang="en">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="****@*****.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Agro">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="488.97">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/btn/x-click-but06.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
        <p></p>
    </a>
</form>
```

**Yahoo email button (works)**

[image: Yahoo email screenshot] -> [image: page open from yahoo mail buy now button]

---

**Other emails button (does not work)**

[image: Gmail screenshot] -> [image: page open from gmail buy now button]

Need solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you use this : `onsubmit="return theMainWindow.showFormWarning(this)" `

Comment: it is built in from paypal.......